# In Django, when a UrlField is made read only, it prevents it from rendering as a clickable link. Why?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-widget

In Django (we are currently using 1.9), when we add an `UrlField` to a model, the Admin site correctly renders the UrlField value as a clickable link on edit views.

If we were to mark this `UrlField` as readonly (through the `ModelAdmin`  `readonly_fields` attribute), the value is then displayed as non-clickable plain text.

- What is a rationale for this behaviour ?
- Is there a way to work around it without changing the widget for the associated form field ?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's just that readonly_fields displays the raw content (using the `__str__()` method) without any widget.

To work it around you might do something like this:

```
class MyAdmin (ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ['myurl_link']

    def myurl_link(self, instance):
        return format_html('<a href="{url}" target=_blank>{url}</a>', url=instance.myurl)
    myurl_link.short_description = _("Website")
```